# Right align user input in python

Tags: python, input, alignment

Im given a question where I have to ask the user for his/her address then split to a new line where there is a comma in the address. After doing that align the whole thing to right, ive been trying to figure this out but I can only do one of the 2, split or align. This is my code:

```
def Q5():
    str = input("Enter your address (separate lines with comma) :\n")

    for c in str:
        print(c, end="")
        if(c == ","):
            print("")


    #print (str.rjust(50))

Q5()
```

Please help me fix this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show an example of what you expect as your output?

Comment: okay so what I exactly want is, try remove the entire for loop and remove the comment from the commented line. When you print the input will be aligned to the right, but what I also want is the input to be aligned to the right and also there should be a new line each time there is a comma in the string.

Comment: Hint: take a look at the `str.split()` method. BTW, please don't use `str` as a variable name as that shadows the built-in `str` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a split function, which takes the splitting character as an argument:

```
x = "this,is,a,string"
split_string = x.split(",")
print split_string
```

returns

```
['this', 'is', 'a', 'string']
```

which is an array that contains all of the words. You want to right-align all of them, so that would be

```
right_aligned = [str.rjust(50) for str in split_string]
```

Then these can be joined by newlines:

```
"\n".join(right_aligned)
```

returns

```
                                          this
                                            is
                                             a
                                        string
```